# How to wire a 6-pin 1/4" audio jack?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, pinout

I'm fairly new to electronics, and I'm working on an amp for my guitar. I need to wire a 1/4" audio jack as the input of the amp. The jack has 6 pins and I'm really confused. I found the datasheet (https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/18/55010643000111_acjx-ihs-771337.pdf), but I still can't understand it. 
[image]

I think "R",  "T", and "S" stand for "ring", "tip", and "sleeve", but what do "RN", "TN", and "SN" stand for? And how should I wire it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you actually care about daisy-chaining the jack to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are switched contacts. When the jack is unplugged R is connected to RN, T to TN, and S to SN.

You can use the contacts to bridge out a jack socket if nothing is plugged in. 
For example on a mic or guitar input I would connect RN to S so that the input is grounded and will be silent when the guitar lead is unplugged from the amp.